# Unable to populate combobox using JSON response

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery mobile for the first time. I want to populate a combobox from the JSON result. Here is the markup of the combobox:

```
<select name="comboChapters" id="comboChapters" data-native-menu="false">
</select>
```

The JSON response is like this:

```
[{"chapterId":1,"chapterName":"First"},{"chapterId":2,"chapterName":"Second"}]
```

And this is the JavaScript function I have written:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#mainPage', function () {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE";
    if (condition === 'ONLINE') {
        var options = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: '/GetChaptersList',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {//populate the combobox
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' +
  data[i].chapterId + '">' +
  data[i].chapterName + '</option>';
                }
                $("#comboChapters").html(options);
            },
        });
    }
    else
        alert('Please connect to the internet.');
});
```

The above code does not work. I have even tried the following code:

```
$(data).each(function() {
  var option = $('<option />');
     option.attr('value', this.chapterId ).text(this.chapterName );
     $('#comboChapters').append(option);
});
```

Can someone point out how it can be done? I need the same functionality for checkbox list as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populating the combobox appears to work. Check this:

```
<select name="comboChapters" id="comboChapters" data-native-menu="false">
```

```
var data = [{"chapterId":1,"chapterName":"First"},{"chapterId":2,"chapterName":"Second"}];

$(data).each(function() {
  var option = $('<option />');
     option.attr('value', this.chapterId ).text(this.chapterName );
     $('#comboChapters').append(option);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qsafmw5g/

Are you sure your request gets the data properly? Is "/GetChaptersList" the right URL?

Edit:
To make it work with jquery mobile you need to add this after the code that populates the options:

```
$('#comboChapters').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsafmw5g/1/

Comment: Still not working for me with static data. Is the data population procedure written in the correct event(pagecreate)?

Comment: The fiddle when run with JQuery mobile selected does not populates the combobox either.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that this is jquery mobile. I have updated the js fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qsafmw5g/1/